# iOS7 App Submission - with only 2x (retina) images?

Tags: iphone, ios7, retina-display, appstore-approval

I'm currently developing an application for iPhone with iOS7, only.
From what I read, for iPhone with iOS7, there is no support for older devices than iPhone4.
If that's the case, when it comes to images, all I need is retina images (@2x).

Can I submit to the App Store, an app with only retina images, since the app's minimal requirement is retina devices ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Can I dump my non-Retina Images for a iOS7 only app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21164232/1146089)

Anyway, as long as I know you don't need @2x version of your images as long as you don't support old displays, but remember that your images as to be double width and height, then if you have a 100x100px UIImageView, you need to load a 200x200px image to meet retina resolution.

EDIT: To explain in deep.

Actually, iPad 2 and iPad mini 1st generation run iOS 7 and [doesn't have retina display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices). Anyway using @2x images it is not mandatary. You can just use double size images and set your UIImageViews' contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill to fit your needs.

PROS -> smaller bundle

CONS -> worst performaces

Comment: Thank you for the link. What about iPad mini? From what I understood it runs iPhone apps as 3.5" (non-retina)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Here there are specs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices for all iOS devices. Anyway you can just use retina images and set contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll look into it.
But the xcode project still throws warnings for the missing images...

Comment: Strange, I don't have any warning... Remember that you still need all the icons and launch images!!

Comment: Managed to solve the warnings issue by going to the imageSet, clicking the empty(!) square of the 1x, and "Remove Selected Item"... I have no idea why, but it worked. Thanks again.