# Are non-retina images required for purely iOS7 apps?

Tags: ios

I'm about to submit my first app and I'm checking I have all images Apple requires. It occurs to me that since iOS7 is not supported on any non-retina devices (correct me if I'm wrong here) and my app is iOS7.1+ only then presumably I shouldn't need to include non-retina images.

Is this correct or does Apple still require these? I note that this link seems to imply the lower res images are still needed for iOS7 apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1

Comment: Cheers- that pointed me in the direction of this even more similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019856/ios7-app-submission-with-only-2x-retina-images/22020152#22020152