# iOS 8 / Xcode 6 is not displaying tab icons properly

Tags: tabs, ios8, xcode6

Is anyone encountering this problem, and have a solution? See the images bellow.

I'm using 50px and 100px @2x images, named for example: `smiley.png` and `smiley@2x.png` correspondingly. However, when I set them on a tab view controller (using the images.xcassets) resource to `smiley`, for example, they appear too large for the tab.

I have gone forth and added `bar item image inset` specifications of 5px to try and mitigate the problem. Now they appear reasonably sized. However when I run the app in the simulator the icons size up and down and sometimes disappear completley from the tab, and re-appear when I switch to another tab. They enlarge and contract when double tapping on them... this is very buggy behaviour.

I want to know if this is just the XCode 6.0.1 or iOS 8 issue, or something I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Side note: To my knowledge, there are no devices which support iOS7 that are non-retina display. That means that since iOS 7, you need to use all @2x.png's and can drop regular .png's. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164232/can-i-dump-my-non-retina-images-for-a-ios7-only-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making my @2x images be 60px square and my regular images be 30px square. I'm still a bit confused now if I'm reading Apple's image specifications wrong, ie, if @2x is 2x what they specify, or the regular images are what they specify / 2?!

Answer (score 1):

I am having exactly the same issue. I am glad I am not the only one. The icons scale randomly every time you press them and finally disappear into zero pixels. The workaround I found was to select the tab images from your Supporting Files folder. Works fine for me with a 120 x 120 image.

It must be a bug, I hope it will be fixed soon.

Edit: above solution does not work! It was a mere coincidence, when I added another ViewController with exactly the same settings, it messed up again.

What does work is the solution mentioned elsewhere in this thread by Victor S: use 30x30 and 60x60 images and put them in a new Image Set in Images.xcassets. Don't use images from your supporting files folder with image insets from the Inspector Menu - Xcode 6 is pretty messy up there and the weirdest things start to happen.